# php preg_match find all parts

Tags: regex

I need to parse string

```
{name "some" 'words' `or` '}\'other staff' in:0 line:`\`}
```

into

```
array("some","words","or","}'other staff","in"=>0, "line"=>"\\")
```

, but preg returns only one match for template, can i do something to get all matches?
here is my regex:

```
    !\{
    (\#?[a-zA-Z0-9\_]{1,16})
    (\.[a-zA-Z0-9\_]{1,16})?
    (?P<args>(?P<arg>
    \ +([a-zA-Z0-9\_]{1,16}\:)?
    \'(\\\\|\\\'|[^\'])*?\'|    //argument in singlequote
    \"([^\\\"]|\\.)*?\"|        //argument in doublequote
    \`[^\`]*?\`|                //argument in backquote
    [0-9]*(\.[0-9]*)?           //argument numeral
    )*?)\ *\}!
```

and i get this:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(12) {
    [0]=>
    string(57) "{name "some" 'words' `or` '}\'other staff' in:0 line:`\`}"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "name"
    [2]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["args"]=>
    string(51) " "some" 'words' `or` '}\'other staff' in:0 line:`\`"
    [3]=>
    string(51) " "some" 'words' `or` '}\'other staff' in:0 line:`\`"
    [4]=>
    string(9) " line:`\`"
    ["arg"]=>
    string(8) "line:`\`" //last argument
    [5]=>
    string(8) "line:`\`"
    [6]=>
    string(5) "line:"
    [7]=>
    string(3) "`\`"
    [8]=>
    string(1) "f"
    [9]=>
    string(1) "e"
  }
}
```

how can i get array of arguments, not the last one?

Comment: I'm not going to even try and parse that monster of a regex. But I can tell you what's going wrong: You're repeating a capturing group, which means that on every repetition of that group, the previous match will be overwritten.

Comment: thats right, the question is how can i do this. There is no limit on args count. so i can get them only in repeat, but then i can't get each part. mb i should to parse the founded list one more time?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to parse it in preg and i need to write it using string functions.